# error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'g_App'

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I wish c++, was a little more specific on the messages they give. The following error is being thrown in the document below

## main.h

```
#ifndef main_h
#define main_h

//includes
#include    <windows.h>
#include    <commctrl.h>
#include    <d3d9.h>
#include    <fstream>

#include "capplication.h"

//constants
#define TITLE "D3D Tut 01: Create Window"
#define WINDOW_X 350
#define WINDOW_Y 320

//Button ID's
#define ID_START 1
#define ID_CANCEL 2

//globals
extern CApplication g_App;

//function prototypes
LRESULT CALLBACK        WindowProcedure(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);

#endif
```

The only header file that could possible throw this error is the capplication.h. given below

## capplication.h

```
#ifndef capplication_h
#define capplication_h

#include"main.h"

class CApplication
{
public:
                        CApplication(void);
                        ~CApplication(void);

    void                InitWindow(void);
    void                SaveSettings(void);
    void                LoadSettings(void);

    void                KillWindow(void);

    inline bool         GetWindowStatus(void)
                        {
                            return m_bRunningWindow;
                        }

    inline HWND         GetWindowHandle(void)
                        {
                            return m_hWindow;
                        }

    inline void         SetWindowStatus(bool bRunningWindow)
                        {
                            m_bRunningWindow = bRunningWindow;
                        }
private:
    bool                m_bRunningWindow;

    HWND    m_hWindow,
            m_hBtnStart,
            m_hBtnCancel,
            m_hLblResolution,
            m_hCbResolution,
            m_hLblBackBuffer,
            m_hCbBackBuffer,
            m_hLblDepthStencil,
            m_hCbDepthStencil,
            m_hLblVertexProcessing,
            m_hCbVertexProcessing,
            m_hLblMultiSampling,
            m_hCbMultiSampling,
            m_hLblAnisotropy,
            m_hCbAnisotropy;

    DWORD   m_dwWidth,
            m_dwHeight,
            m_dwVertexProcessing,
            m_dwAnisotropy;

    D3DFORMAT           m_ColorFormat,
                        m_DepthStencilFormat;

    D3DMULTISAMPLE_TYPE m_MultiSampling;
};

#endif
```

Besides that, the only suspicious thing I see is fstream given in the first code. I did have it as
fstream.h

But VC++ was not recognizing it so I was told to remove the h and I did. now I am down to this error. and I have no clue what it could be. Possibly something obvious

Comment: I had this problem, and I was including a header file from a different project within the same solution. Newbie mistake, I know, but I don't write in C++ that often.

Answer (score 4):

You have a circular inclusion problem. main.h includes capplication.h, and then capplication.h includes main.h. Remember that in C++, inclusion is a literal copy-and-paste of the contents of the included header. What is happening is that when main.h includes capplication.h, the include statement that brings main.h in again happens before the delcaration of the CApplication class, and so when main.h is processed for the second time, the line `extern CApplication g_App` is reached before the declaration of the CApplication class is.

It doesn't really make sense for a capplication.h to include main.h, so you should move anything that capplication.h needs out from main.h into a separate header, and then have both main.h and capplication.h include that header.

For future reference, the message "syntax error: missing ';' before identifier" *usually* means that the type you are trying to declare the variable in question as has not been defined.

Comment: That makes sense. But when I do that, it catches errors within capplication.h which comes before the original error i was having.  This is not my code . I am actually trying to do a tutorial at http://www.two-kings.de/tutorials/dxgraphics/dxgraphics01.html. it also has a circular inclusion in its code.

Comment: It's bad style, yes, that the headers depend on each other, but they each have include guards. If `main.h` is included, then `main_h` is defined, `capplication.h` is included, `capplication_h` is defined, `main.h` is included, but `main_h` is defined so the PP goes back to `capplication.h`, then to `main.h`. It appears to me that the definition of class `CApplication` would be above `extern CApplication g_App;` in the translation unit.

Answer (score 4):

```
extern CApplication g_App;  // missing ‘;’ before identifier ‘g_App’
```

What could possibly go wrong with this line?  The error message itself isn't particularly self-explanatory, but with only a little experience, it's clear that the likely culprit is that it doesn't know what `CApplication` is at this point.

How could this happen?  I expect Visual Studio has an option to display preprocessor output, but you can do it in your head too.  If the `.cpp` source file includes *main.h*, what text gets included?  (The text of *main.h*, and within it the text of *capplication.h*.)  If the source file includes *capplication.h*, what text gets included?  (The blank line at the top of *capplication.h*, then the text of *main.h*, then the rest of *capplication.h* with the definition of `CApplication`.  What went wrong?)

Does *main.h* really need to #include *capplication.h* or would a declaration of the class suffice for the purposes of declaring `g_App`?

```
// in main.h
class CApplication;
extern CApplication g_App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `main.h` does not need to include `capplication.h` in order to declare `extern CApplication g_App`. You could try:

```
#ifndef main_h
#define main_h

//includes
#include    <windows.h>
#include    <commctrl.h>
#include    <d3d9.h>
#include    <fstream>

//constants
#define TITLE "D3D Tut 01: Create Window"
#define WINDOW_X 350
#define WINDOW_Y 320

//Button ID's
#define ID_START 1
#define ID_CANCEL 2

//globals
class CApplication;
extern CApplication g_App;

//function prototypes
LRESULT CALLBACK        WindowProcedure(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);

#endif
```